# Capybara: Finding a second checkbox which is identical to the first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, capybara

I am writing tests for view files. I have a page with two checkboxes which allows the user to Select All items in two different lists. However, the checkboxes are part of a partial so are identical. I have managed to check the first one using:

```
first(:checkbox, "Select all").click
```

But I am unable to check the second. I have tried replacing `first` with `last` and with `second` but to no avail.
I think I may need to use the `find` selector but am struggling with that also. Any help much appreciated.
Thanks

**UPDATE**

It appears that this in fact **another issue**. I *think* that any checkbox that impacts on other checkboxes does not work as expected when "checked" by Capybara. So the current answers below work in the sense that they do check the checkbox, but the expected behaviour does not occur i.e. the checkboxes linked to them do not get "checked". I may be wrong though.

Comment: can you give an id for each checkbox. this will make things a lot easier.

Comment: i'm working on view files that I didn't create and I didn't think I was able to edit. They did not have IDs and they had the same class.
I think i'm going to have to add IDs to them to solve this. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops. Turns out it was a JS issue and not Capybara macthers! Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
# find the second checkbox
find('input[type="checkbox"]:nth-child(2)').click
```

Comment: Apologies, but this doesn't seem to be working:
`Failure/Error: find('input[type="checkbox"]:nth-child(1)').click`
     `Capybara::ElementNotFound:`
       `Unable to find css "input[type=\"checkbox\"]:nth-child(1)"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use find all

```
all('input[type="checkbox"]', :text => 'Select all')[1].click
```

Comment: Apologies, but this doesn't seem to be working:
`Failure/Error: all('input[type="checkbox"]', :text => 'Select all')[1].click`
    `NoMethodError:`
       `undefined method \`click' for nil:NilClass'`

Comment: @HatStephensWork - Nafaa and I took a complete guess at how to identify the checkbox in your HTML.  It's possible that it's something completely different.

You'll need to inspect and see whether your checkbox has some kind of ID or div that you can actually click on.